# Telerik Rad Grid: Set default value on edit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, telerik-grid

I've got a Telerik RadGrid databound through a LINQ query and I have a value that I'd like to set automatically to true when a record has been edited (essentially a flag that it's been touched).  I seem to recall having done this once upon a time but can't recall how or find anything in the demos...

Comment: What you are looking for is the `dirty` field in your kendo model. This is already built in.

Comment: Not using Kendo :(

Answer (score 0):

The `dirty` field in kendo is used to know if the grid is changed. Similar to the one in Telerik RadGrid is the Batch Editing mode. Say if you want to update the table, you use Batch Editing mode to edit the fields and when you click save, you will have the collection of those rows which are edited / inserted / deleted.

You can look up more about Batch Editing [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/edit-mode/batch-editing/overview). The similar to the "dirty" field is only available in the Batch Editing Mode.